# Sequentially running multiple setIntervals

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm trying to run multiple `setInterval()`'s but I'm having trouble with the asynchronous aspect of doing this.

This example is almost identical to what I'm trying to achieve:

```
var labels = ["Bacon", "Beer", "Steak"];
var second, timer;
labels.forEach(function(label){
    second = 0;
    timer = setInterval(function(){
        console.log(label + ' is awesome ' + second);
        if(second === 10) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
        second++;
    }, 1000);
});
```

Because of setInterval being asynchronous the three intervals are running in parallel and are messing up the interval:

> Bacon is awesome 0
>
> Beer is awesome 1
>
> Steak is awesome 2
>
> Beer is awesome 3
>
> Bacon is awesome 4
>
> Steak is awesome 5
>
> Bacon is awesome 6
>
> Beer is awesome 7
>
> Steak is awesome 8
>
> Bacon is awesome 9
>
> Beer is awesome 10
>
> Beer is awesome 11
>
> Bacon is awesome 12
>
> Beer is awesome 13
>
> Bacon is awesome 14
>
> Bacon is awesome 15
>
> Beer is awesome 16
>
> Beer is awesome 17
>
> Bacon is awesome 18
>
> Bacon is awesome 19
>
> Beer is awesome 20
>
> Beer is awesome 21
>
> Bacon is awesome 22
>
> Bacon is awesome 23
>
> ...

I'm wondering how to enforce some sort of queue so that the first interval runs it's course then when 10 seconds are up the next setInterval is executed?

I've tried quickly with the [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) library but I had trouble finding a suitable control flow.

Comment: setInterval() isn't asynchronous

Comment: Can you add your desired output to the question?

Comment: Yes, the desired output would be nice

Comment: Hey sorry for delay. Desired output would be: Bacon is awesome 0, bacon is awesome 1..10, then beer is awesome 0, beer is awesome 1..10

Answer (score 2):

This was good for me to practice some OO style Javascript :)

```
    function Timer(name) {
    var self = this;
    this.name = name;
    this.count = 0;
    this.x = setInterval(function () {
        if (self.count++ == 9) {
            clearInterval(self.x);
        }
        console.log(self.name + ' ' + self.count + ' is awesome');
    }, 1000);
}



var labels = ["Bacon", "Beer", "Steak"];
labels.forEach(function (label) {
    new Timer(label);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CSefJ/2/)**

Comment: Good answer, i think OP wants it to run till 10 though, `if(self.count++ ===10)`

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants, I think he wants them to run one after another.

Comment: @howderek you, could be right, but his description is open to some interpretation

Answer (score 2):

I made a little function called `callQueue' that calls an Array filled with functions in order a certain number of times with a certain interval between them

**Usage**

The first argument is the array of functions, the second the number of times they should be called, the third is the time between the calls.

```
callQueue([

function () {
    isAwesome('bacon');
},

function () {
    isAwesome('beer');
},

function () {
    isAwesome('steak');
}], 10, 1000);
```

**The Function**

```
function callQueue(queue, times, timeBetween) {
    var i = 0;
    k = 0;
    queue.forEach(function (func) {
        for (k = 0; k < times; k += 1) {
            alert(i * timeBetween);
            i += 1;
            setTimeout(func, (i * timeBetween));
        }
    });
};
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/L5nhU/

Answer (score 2):

You could *e.g.* use `setTimeout` without a loop at all, and pick the right label from within the function.

```
var labels   = ["Bacon", "Beer", "Steak"],
    steps    = 10,
    total    =  0,
    step     =  0,
    sequence =  0,
    label    = labels [0];

(function fn (){
    if (step === steps && sequence === labels.length - 1) {
        return;
    } else if(step === steps) {
        label = labels [++sequence];
        step  = 0;
    }  

    console.log(label + ' is awesome ' + total);

    step++;
    total++;
    setTimeout (fn, 1000)
})();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LSC96/1/)

Or e.g. keep the loop and use the index and your number of steps as multiplier as timeout, to delay the other timeouts accordingly.

```
var labels = ["Bacon", "Beer", "Steak"],
    steps = 10,
    total = 0;
labels.forEach(function(label, index){
    var step = 0;
        setTimeout (function fn (){
            if(step === steps) {
                return;
            }

            console.log(label + ' is awesome ' + total);

            step++;
            total++;
            setTimeout (fn, 1000)
        },( (steps + 1)* index ) * 1000);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vnD3g/3)

Or wrap your `setInterval` in a `setTimeout`.

```
var labels = ["Bacon", "Beer", "Steak"];
labels.forEach(function(label, index){
    setTimeout (function () {
           var second = 0;
           var timer = setInterval(function(){
                console.log(label + ' is awesome ' + second);
                if(second === 10) {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                }
                second++;
            }, 1000);
    },index * 11 * 1000);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mHA4g/1/)

All produce

```
Bacon is awesome 0
Bacon is awesome 1
Bacon is awesome 2
Bacon is awesome 3
Bacon is awesome 4
Bacon is awesome 5
Bacon is awesome 6
Bacon is awesome 7
Bacon is awesome 8
Bacon is awesome 9
Beer is awesome 0
Beer is awesome 1
Beer is awesome 2
Beer is awesome 3 
...
```

Comment: wow this answer really deserves at least one upvote. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've called `setInterval` and `setTimeout` you're in the hands of the browser; the time that passes isn't guaranteed to be exact and the order that multiple callbacks are executed in aren't guaranteed to be exact - and usually won't be.

If you want to enforce order of execution, using `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` will give you the opportunity to decide what happens when each callback completes.

Here's a fiddle that iterates over the Bacons first, then Beers, then Steaks: http://jsfiddle.net/q96Vc/

And here's one that displays each label one after the other until 30 seconds is up: http://jsfiddle.net/DtbZ6/1/

You could even expand on either of these examples to use three separate calls to `setTimeout` that won't get repeated until the three previous calls have all been executed, which would mean the order of the three would vary but they would never overlap.